# $('tbody tr')[0].offset().top doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I try to get the top of the first row in the tbody in a table by:

```
$('tbody tr')[0].offset().top
```

but, I can get any value from it.

I read an article that the parent element of the target element should be set position property in CSS. So, I added:

```
tbody {
  position: relative;
}
```

but it still doesn't work.

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
  const val = $('tbody tr')[0].offset().top;
  console.log(val);
});
```

I expect the output in number of the offset top position of the "tr" element.

Comment: maybe try with `$('tbody tr:first').offset().top`

Comment: `$()[0]` gives you the DOM node, `.offset()` needs a jquery object ie `$($("tbody tr")[0]).offset().top` - but that's pointless when you can use `:first` or `.first()`

Comment: thanks! "`.offset()` needs a jquery object". This is what I wanted to know.  @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the `offset().top` of the first `tr` then use `$('tbody tr:first').offset().top;`

Lets say you want to get the third `tr` then use `$('tbody tr').eq(2).offset().top`

**Working demo**

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  const val = $('tbody tr:first').offset().top;
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```